# Как сделать запись в колонку, при условии ее существования?

Tags: mysql, запрос

Как сделать проверку в запросе, если колонка(поле) в таблице существует, тогда происходит запись в нее. Вот моя попытка:

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `col1` = 1, `col2` = 2, IF(EXISTS(`c`), `col3` = 3)
```

Comment: вытащить схему таблицы, проверить есть ли колонка, сформировать нужный запрос (видимо вы из пхп это делаете?) и выполнить его. Проверить наличие столбца можно так https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264865/1216425

Comment: @teran, знаю этот способ, но я надеялся, что есть проще метод. Если другого варианта не будет, придется этот использовать. Спасибо.

Comment: А какой другой вариант вы представляете? Его просто нет  в рамках возможностей ansi-92. Или, если вы из PHP делаете, то абсурд: вызвать код, отловить эксепшн "нет такого поля" (по-моему точно это не сделать), если эксепшена нет - то делать запись. Никто так не делает.

Comment: @AK, понял, думал что функционал побогаче